# Unable to Embed google scripts in a frame

Tags: java, gwt, google-apps-script, embedding

I am using GWT App and trying to embed google scripts in a frame for ex link is 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx4pkrxYX2_6rcsu5VrcINZ8IJjmxqUVk7KW-fqelGfYHLq9nU/exec' but nothing coming up on frame .

Instead error is produced in console saying 'Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyRzTv5ZpUdFMsf5FVdp1F_3DjeZ4w3c8vEk-poY_YEUlIuzOY/exec does not permit cross-origin framing
'

Comment: I am using java with Gwt which is a compiler that convert java to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

By design and a dup of others in s.o. look at the error message. You cant iframe an apps script except ln certain google-owned domains like google sites.